# Change Tab Label Android

Tags: android, tabs, label, android-tabhost

As you can read in the title, i'd like to change dynamically the label
in my tabs.
The thing is, im using a ta host and tabspec to create my tabs, here an example of a tab :

```
    TabSpec sourceSelect = tabHost.newTabSpec("Source Select");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    sourceSelect.setIndicator("Source Select");
    final Intent selectIntent = new Intent(this, FileListActivity.class);
    sourceSelect.setContent(selectIntent);
```

When i come and say **sourceSelect.setText("") it wont do anything**, it compiles tho.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using a custom layout for your tab indicator, you have to get the tab spec by its index in the tab widget (0 based). It's a pretty lame implementation, but I searched and searched for an answer to this for my app and this is the only thing that has worked so far:

```
((TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
            .findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setText("This sucks, I know.");
```

Another option is to use setIndicator(View view) and input a text view with the desired text if you are not afraid of the Garbage Collector.

Of course, you can combine the two - if you're using a custom tab indicator and its text view's id is, for example, R.id.text_view_tab:

```
((TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
            .findViewById(R.id.text_view_tab)).setText("This is still ugly and hacky, though.");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately the method setIndicator(View view) only works for Android 1.6 and up (version 4) and since Im using a lower version I can't use it. Where do you define id.text_view_tab or id.title to assign it to the tab ?

Comment: Since you are using a lower version, the title's id would be android.R.id.title. It's defined by the framework itself, you don't need to manually define it anywhere - just use it to set the text.


android.R are system defined default IDs, like if you don't assign an ID to a listview, you can refer it with findViewById(android.R.list).


Try the first approach I suggested and tell me if it works - at least it worked for me...